# Batch File Printing

Tags: windows, printing, batch-processing

I have a user that has to print out about 220 documents averaging 2-3 pages each. When printed using the standard Windows method of Select All - Right-click - Print it overwhelms either the print server or the printer itself. I am looking for a utility that will allow me to process say 5 documents at a time that will do all of the documents in a given directory. I am hoping this will alleviate strain on the print server and will also allow the user to not have to babysit his print jobs. I found one that lets you schedule a print job for a certain time, but (and maybe this isn't a deal breaker) the spelling in the program is atrocious.

Comment: What versions of windows are you using?

Comment: also, can you include the name of the program you found already?

Comment: What kind of documents? Some solutions only work well, or at all, with certain kinds.

Comment: Why not rather understand the reason for the real problem and work out why the spooler dies? This would b a more general solution, and certainly seems more robust.  What symptoms/errors is the printing subsystem reporting?

Answer (score 2):

Answering an old question to build reputation points :P

This VBS opens and prints a word doc:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\scripts\inventory.doc")

objDoc.PrintOut()
objWord.Quit
```

This VBS loops through files in a folder:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Scripts"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
```

This VBS causes the PC to wait 60 seconds, so as not to overwhelm the print server:

```
WScript.sleep 60000
```

Combining these:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Scripts"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile)

    objDoc.PrintOut()
    objWord.Quit
    WScript.sleep 60000
Next
```

Change your "objStartFolder" to the folder where the word docs are located, and make sure there are only word docs in that folder.  Save that code to a text file and change the extension to "vbs".  It can be launched via double-click or by windows scheduler, so you can launch it in the middle of the night or wotnot.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're talking about MS Word)  I'm not a Word expert by any stretch, but you could use a bit of VBA to do the trick, launching winword.exe from a script.  I've seen it done, but never got sufficiently involved to provide any more info.